# jQuery stop event after running if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

How do I make this if statement stop after the correct answer is chosen? Do I need to change it to if else, or is there something else I can try?

if

```
if (!arraysEqual(answerKey, answers)) {
    alert('Please Try Again');
    return false;
}

if (arraysEqual(answerKey, answers)) {
    $("#bin ol").append('<a href="index.html" name="modal"><img id="correct" src="images/visSelect/seq_correct.png"></a>');
    return false;
}
});
```

if else (updated)

```
if (arraysEqual(answerKey, answers)) {
    $("#bin ol").append('<a href="index.html" name="modal"><img id="correct" src="images/visSelect/seq_correct.png"></a>');
    return false;
}else{
    alert('Please Try Again');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `if..else` looks better in your case for the case that you call `arraysEquals` twice.

Comment: Regarding some basics in programming with Javascript there is some good resources here:[Mozilla Developer Network - JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript). Regarding if..else specific see this: [JavaScript Refeence - if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if..else` looks better considering the case that you would be calling `arraysEquals` twice if it returns true.

In the first case, the function `arraysEquals` will be called twice if it returns true..

but in the second case.. the function will be called only once in all cases and overall it looks more clear to me.

Comment: I see what you mean. Does it look a bit better now? I took your advice and cleaned it up a bit.

Comment: @user1791449 You don't need an return false if that condition is the only code in that function.

Comment: How do I keep the else alert from running if the array is equal?

Comment: @user1791449: [JavaScript Refeence - if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)